# problema filtrando emails con regexp

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Estoy tratando de hacer una expresión regular que no permita que la gente ponga `@gmail`, `@hotmail`, etc.

He estado intentando con un tester de expresiones regulares en línea y tengo esta solución:

```
(?=^((?!@gmail\.).)*$)(?=^((?!@yahoo\.).)*$)(?=^((?!@outlook\.). )*$)(?=^((?!@hotmail\.).)*$)
```

Funciona en el entorno de test, pero cuando trato de ponerlo como el patrón de mi campo de entrada, no se comporta de la misma manera

¿Alguien sabe porque es así?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<form action="" method="get" class="form-example">
  <div class="form-example" id="res">
    <label for="email">Enter your email: </label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email"  pattern= "(?=^((?!@gmail\.).)*$)(?=^((?!@yahoo\.).)*$)(?=^((?!@outlook\.).)*$)(?=^((?!@hotmail\.).)*$)" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-example">
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe!" >
  </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo que agregues un [example] para que podamos reproducir tu error y sea más fácil ayudarte. Saludos!

Comment: Añadi el formulario con el que estoy haciendo pruebas

Answer (score 0):

intenta poner la expReg de esta forma = `([^@ \t\r\n]+@(gmail|hotmail|yahoo)\.com)`

espero te sirva saludos

quedaría de esta forma =

```
<form action="" method="get" class="form-example">
    <div class="form-example" id="res">
      <label for="email">Enter your email: </label>
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email"  pattern= "([^@ \t\r\n]+@(gmail|hotmail|yahoo)\.com)" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-example">
      <input type="submit" value="Subscribe!" >
    </div>
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    
  
    
  
  </script>
```